# Tool to visualise how HTTP traffic is split into TCP packets?

Tags: http, tcp, visualization

I am writing a webserver of my own and I’m trying to tune its behaviour.

For this purpose, it would be nice to be able to see exactly how the HTTP traffic is split into individual TCP packets.

Is there a tool that can visualise this nicely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is a network sniffer which can [show and save HTTP transactions](http://linuxonly.nl/docs/38/117_Wireshark.html).

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark or Netmon (http://www.fiddler2.com/redir/?id=netmon) will do this. You might like the VRTA tool for Netmon (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21462) which helps make sense of HTTP traffic when looking at a low-level capture.